# Progress bar not shown Phonegap/Android

Tags: android, cordova

I am using Phonegap with my Android project and i am not able to see the Progress Bar here is my code.

My Main class inherites the DroidGap class

```
this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS,
                Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
final Activity MyActivity = this;
        this.appView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                // Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes
                // string to Loading...
                MyActivity.setTitle("    Please wait");
                MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100); // Make the bar
                                                        // disappear after URL
                                                        // is loaded

                // Return the app name after finish loading
                if (progress == 100)
                    MyActivity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }

        });
        this.appView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                    String description, String failingUrl) {
                // Handle the error
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Nothing happens any idea if i try the same for a simple WebView it works properly...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, using Phonegap 1.0 and overriding the `DroidGap::init` method to include code like the OP posted. I could tell that `onProgressChanged` was called because messages printed to the log did show up, but the progress bar did not show. Eventually I found a solution.

In the `onCreate` method of `DroidGap`, the window title is switched off:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

This needs to be commented out for the progress bar to show.

My suggestion is to copy the whole `DroidGap.java` file to a new class (let's say `DroidGapModified`), add the progress bar changes and extend this new class from your main app.

Comment: Where can i get teh whole dropdgap.java from?